# How to write UNITS power in decimal value?

Tags: java

I am using Javax.Units package in my project, to write some formual's. I am trying to write this line of code:

```
Unit newton = SI.NEWTON;
Unit newton09 = newton.pow(0.9);//not allowing me to input decimal value 0.9
```

The **pow** method only takes **int** as parameter, but I am looking for float or double as parameters.How can i write float or double in parameter?

Comment: You can't pass a `float` or `double` into a method that takes an `int`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog, I am looking for a way to pass float or double, if possible.

Comment: It is not possible if the method takes an `int` parameter.

Comment: k thanks, is there any alternative classes or API i can use, to pass the float or double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a step back and recall what exponentiation means, especially with fractional exponents. You are trying to raise some value `X` to some power `M/N`.

If you recall what `M/N` means from your arithmetic class, it is the same as `M * 1/N`. This is important because it means you can phrase your expression like this:

```
X^M^(1/n)
```

So we have this equivalence :

```
X^(M/N) == X^M^(1/N)
```

and anything raised to the `1/N` is the same as taking the `N`th root, so you can have an equivalent expression by computing this:

```
Nroot( X^M )
```

which in that API, would be:

```
Unit newton09 = newton.pow(9).root(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `root()` and `pow()` methods. A number, `n`, taken to the 0.9 power is equivalent to `n` taken to the 9/10 power, which in turn is equal to the 10th root of (`n` taken to the 9th power). So, you could have this using only `int`s:

```
Unit newton09 = newton.pow(9).root(10);
```